# Out of band signature application for banking transactions

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I work on a banking signature project.

Signing transactions must be carried out on another application to respect the mechanism "Out Of Band". When the user makes a transaction, he must pass to a second application (out of band) in which he will find the list of tasks awaiting for signature.

Details:

The existing policy is that the user signs his transactions in the same application, i.e. on the banking application, by entering a SMS OTP.

The current objective is that the signature task should be done in another app, to strengthen security measures.

The user already has an account in the bank app, and should create a new account in the signature app, in order to sign his transactions safely.

After creating the new account, and after authentication, the user should find the list of tasks awaiting for signature, which were transferred from the bank application.

How can I match the user in both applications, so that I can transfer his unique tasks to sign

I do not know how the exchange of data between the two applications (the bank application and the signature app) will work, and how can I secure the signature app?

Comment: Can you describe the second application?  Has it been written yet?  If so, what technology it is using?

Comment: Details :

the existing policy is that the user sign his transactions in the same application, ie on the banking application, by entering a SMS OTP.

the current objectif, is that the signature task should be done in another app,to strengthen security measures.

the user has already an account in the bank app, and should create a new account in the signature app,in order to sign his transactions safely.

after creating the new account, and after authentication,the user should find the list of tasks awaiting for signature,wich were transferred from the bank application.

Comment: I'm in the phase of conception and reflexion . the technology i'll use is java/jee

Comment: Yes, e-signature use case is not uncommon in banking. The reason I ask about the second app is because I want to know what options you have.  It looks like the second app is not built yet.  In this case, you want to think about do you want your second app "Pull" or being "Push" notification.  Also, you want to think about how the second app users get notified.  1. By email / text message,  2. By pop windows.   All of them will affect the technology and architecture of your over all solution and security functions involved.

Comment: @Abelard Chow thank u for ur answer,

Comment: No problem.  Let me organize my last reply into an answer.  Hope everything goes well with your project

Answer (score 0):

Since the second app is not built yet, you want to think about should the second app "Pull" or being "Push" notification. Also, you want to think about how the second app users get notified. 1. By email / text message, 2. By pop windows. All of them will affect the technology and architecture of your over all solution and security functions involved.